# 502 Bad Gateway and unhealthy probe in AGIC AppGW

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ingress-controller

My application is with Angular FE and multiple Asp.net core web api's. I have deployed this in AKS and configured Appgw AGIC.
My Ingress controller details

```
Name:             ingress-appgw-deployment-xxxxxxxx-xxxx
Namespace:        kube-system
Priority:         0
Service Account:  ingress-appgw-sa
Node:             aks-agentpool-xxxxxxx-vmss000000/10.224.1.255
Start Time:       Fri, 01 Mar 2024 02:16:47 +0400
Labels:           app=ingress-appgw
                  kubernetes.azure.com/managedby=aks
                  pod-template-hash=6d4f68fc9f
Annotations:      checksum/config: 1e53b6ba909ce787812767da80976912cc41007f8a716c489edab91f215b2bd7
                  cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: true
                  kubernetes.azure.com/metrics-scrape: true
                  prometheus.io/path: /metrics
                  prometheus.io/port: 8123
                  prometheus.io/scrape: true
                  resource-id:
                    /subscriptions/ea88e1ed-fec0-472f-87f5-a00e6a608f19/resourceGroups/AZ-BELSIO-SOFTWARES-RG/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClus...
Status:           Running
IP:               10.224.x.xx
IPs:
  IP:           10.224.x.xx
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/ingress-appgw-deployment-6d4f68fc9f
Containers:
  ingress-appgw-container:
    Container ID:   containerd://de72b0a2d86ffd7e11113b0ee38a374b509b212d56eac166391d28d4ae81849c
    Image:          mcr.microsoft.com/azure-application-gateway/kubernetes-ingress:1.7.2
    Image ID:       mcr.microsoft.com/azure-application-gateway/kubernetes-ingress@sha256:eeb1d42ebfb872478d9b0b16f6936ea938d6e5eed4a59cde332b8757556a5e1f
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 01 Mar 2024 02:18:47 +0400
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Fri, 01 Mar 2024 02:17:55 +0400
      Finished:     Fri, 01 Mar 2024 02:17:56 +0400
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  4
    Limits:
      cpu:     700m
      memory:  600Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   20Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:8123/health/alive delay=15s timeout=1s period=20s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:8123/health/ready delay=5s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment Variables from:
      ingress-appgw-cm  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:
      AGIC_POD_NAMESPACE:             kube-system (v1:metadata.namespace)
      KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR:   belsio-dns-yvu9cnmb.hcp.uaenorth.azmk8s.io
      KUBERNETES_PORT:                tcp://myapp-dns-yvu9cnmb.hcp.uaenorth.azmk8s.io:443
      KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP:        tcp://myapp-dns-yvu9cnmb.hcp.uaenorth.azmk8s.io:443
      KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:        myapp-dns-yvu9cnmb.hcp.uaenorth.azmk8s.io
      AZURE_CLOUD_PROVIDER_LOCATION:  /etc/kubernetes/azure.json
      AGIC_POD_NAME:                  ingress-appgw-deployment-6d4f68fc9f-xtlmk (v1:metadata.name)
    Mounts:
      /etc/kubernetes/azure.json from cloud-provider-config (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-9kcms (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  cloud-provider-config:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/kubernetes/azure.json
    HostPathType:  File
  kube-api-access-9kcms:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

My ingress congiguration

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app.example.com
  rules:
  - host: app.example.com
    http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: angular
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api1
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: api1
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: api2
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Expected: domain root path will route to Angular App and /api1 and /api2 to api's. I was able to achieve this in minikube using nginx IC using the same ingress configuration.

Issue: Angular is accessible but cannot access API's. I checked APIs by assigning a public and it's accessible but cannot with the ingress. In the health check, Angular pods are healthy but api pods are unhealth with the below message.

"Received invalid status code: 404 in the backend server’s HTTP response. As per the health probe configuration, 200-399 is the acceptable status code. Either modify probe configuration or resolve backend issues. To learn more visit - [https://aka.ms/StatusCodeMismatch."](https://aka.ms/StatusCodeMismatch.%22)

Please help me fix this and also suggest additional configurations that you think might help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can try modifying the health probe configuration to accept the 404 status code. You can also check the backend server to ensure that it is functioning correctly and returning the expected response. Additionally, you may want to check the network security group associated with the AKS nodes and the AKS subnet to ensure that they are not blocking traffic from the load balancer or application gateway to the AKS nodes.

Comment: Thanks @Arko. The issue was with the routing in the .NET code and was resolved by adding a root prefix for Swagger UI.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the routing in the .NET code and was resolved by adding a root prefix for Swagger UI.

blog by CodeMaze helped.
https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-modify-a-base-uri-of-swagger/